# blackberry use url from browser in my application

Tags: blackberry, browser, menuitem

I have a simple application:I added new `MenuItem` to the browser and it works perfectly.
I want that when I click on this `MenuItem`, it should take me to my app with the current url at the browser.

Comment: Put your sample code snippet here;

Answer (score 1):

> **browserField.getDocumentUrl()** gives the current URL of the browser;

Try like this sample code:

```
public class FirstScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener
{
private BrowserField browserField;
private ButtonField click;
private MenuItem goBack=new MenuItem("GO Back",100,101) 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        goBackFromBrower();
    }
};
public FirstScreen()
{        
    setTitle("First Screen");
    click=new ButtonField("Click", Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    click.setChangeListener(this);
    add(click);        
    addMenuItem(goBack);
}        

protected void goBackFromBrower() 
{
    String str=browserField.getDocumentUrl();       
    delete(browserField);
    System.out.println("============= URL: "+str);
    Status.show(str, 1000);
}

public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context)
{
    browserField=new BrowserField();
    add(browserField);
    browserField.requestContent("http://www.google.com/news/");         
}
protected boolean onSavePrompt() 
{
    return true;
}      
}
```

Comment: thank you , but this is not what i'm looking for :( , maybe if you read the qustion well it will be clear for you :)